# Drag and drop nested list order with data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drag and drop list of parent and child categories. I want to set the data attributes to the numerical order when I hit the test button. The parent data attribute currently works. But I'm having trouble getting the child data attribute to work correctly.

So for each parent, the child category should be number 1,2,3... and then the count should reset for the next parent. Right now the child doesn't reset for the new parent. How can I get the child to reference its parent so I can get the counter to reset?

Not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this. The end goal is to grab those data attributes and use that number to update the orderId in the database.

```js
$(".categories").sortable({
  connectWith: ".categories",
  placeholder: "placeholder",

  start: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.helper.hasClass('child-category')) {
      ui.placeholder.removeClass('placeholder');
      ui.placeholder.addClass('placeholder-sub');
    } else {
      ui.placeholder.removeClass('placeholder-sub');
      ui.placeholder.addClass('placeholder');
    }
  },
  sort: function(event, ui) {
    var pos;
    if (ui.helper.hasClass('child-category')) {
      pos = ui.position.left + 20;
      $('#cursor').text(ui.position.left + 20);
    } else if (ui.helper.hasClass('parent-category')) {
      pos = ui.position.left;
      $('#cursor').text(ui.position.left);
    }
    if (pos >= 32 && !ui.helper.hasClass('child-category')) {
      ui.placeholder.removeClass('placeholder');
      ui.placeholder.addClass('placeholder-sub');
      ui.helper.addClass('child-category');
      ui.helper.removeClass('parent-category');

    } else if (pos < 25 && ui.helper.hasClass('child-category')) {
      ui.placeholder.removeClass('placeholder-sub');
      ui.placeholder.addClass('placeholder');
      ui.helper.removeClass('child-category');
      ui.helper.addClass('parent-category');
    }
  }
});

               
            $(".category").attr("data-order-parent", "");
            $(".category").attr("data-order-child", "");
            var i = 1;
            $(".parent-category").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("data-order-parent", i);
                var j = 1;
                $(".child-category").each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("data-order-child", j);
                    j++;
                });
                i++;
            });
```

```css
.categories {
  list-style: none outside none;
}

.category {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: move;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 480px;
}

.category:hover {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.child-category {
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 440px;
}

.placeholder {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  width: 480px;
}

.placeholder-sub {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  width: 440px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<button id="TEST" type="button">TEST</button>

<ul class='categories'>
  <li class="category parent-category" data-order-parent="" data-order-child="">
    categoryName-1
  </li>
  <li class="category parent-category" data-order-parent="" data-order-child="">
    categoryName-2
  </li>
  <li class="category parent-category" data-order-parent="" data-order-child="">
    categoryName-3
  </li>
  <li class="category parent-category" data-order-parent="" data-order-child="">
    categoryName-4
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just iterate over your categories only once: children always follow after the last parent, so it is not so difficult to keep track.

Add this to the `sortable` object argument:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(".category").attr("data-order-parent", "");
    $(".category").attr("data-order-child", "");
    var i = 1, j = 1;
    $(".category").each(function() { // Iterate all categories (not only parents)
        if ($(this).is(".parent-category")) { // Is it parent or child?
            $(this).attr("data-order-parent", i++);
            j = 1; // Reset child counter
        } else {
            $(this).attr("data-order-child", j++);
        }
    });
}
```